# Want to match embedded field and return distinct records

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection which stores document like below for each year .Inside holiday array it stores holiday_date which has date on which there is holiday . Now there can be 2 holidays for a single date . Like it can be a sunday and can be a diwali also . Want I want here is to find number of distinct records  for a particular year and month. More specifically I want to pass year and month , the year passed will compare with "year" field and month passed will compare with "holiday_date" field's month and will give us just distinct records(unique for each date).

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55276ffd203340d01483d2a7"),
"year" : "2015",
"holidays" : [ 
    {
        "holiday_date" : ISODate("2015-04-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "event" : "diwali",
        "weekday" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55279855a78a431805b94ae8")
    }, 
    {
        "holiday_date" : ISODate("2015-04-28T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "event" : "1212",
        "weekday" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5527848042336d001cdae82b")
    }, 
    {
        "holiday_date" : ISODate("2015-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "event" : "fd",
        "weekday" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55277c05c83d4d8813f94f14")
    }, 
    {
        "holiday_date" : ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "event" : "xzcxc",
        "weekday" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55277c05c83d4d8813f94f13")
    }, 
    {
        "holiday_date" : ISODate("2015-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "event" : "fd",
        "weekday" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55277bdec83d4d8813f94f12")
    }, 
    {
        "holiday_date" : ISODate("2015-04-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "event" : "ssdds",
        "weekday" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("55277bd0c83d4d8813f94f11")
    }
],
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use following snippet

```
db.stores.aggregate(
{ $unwind: '$holidays' },
{$match: {'year': "2015"}},
{$match: {
        created_date : {
            $gte:{'$holidays.holiday_date':'2015-04-01T04:00:00Z'}, 
            $lt:  {'$holidays.holiday_date':'2015-05-01T04:00:00Z'}
      }
    }},
{$group: {
        '_id': {
            'day': {'$dayOfMonth': '$holidays.holiday_date'},
            'month': {'$month': '$holidays.holiday_date'},
            'year': {'$year': '$holidays.holiday_date'},
            'event': '$holidays.event'
        },
        count: { $sum:  1 },
       ids: { $push: "$_id" }

    }
}
)
```

You can set month like following

```
var startMonth = new Date("01,11,1992");  
var endMonth = startMonth.setMonth(12);
```

Thanks